# problems with the distance between the side plot and main plot using ggside

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using `ggside` to plot a contour plot as a main plot and a spectrum on the left y-axis and the top x-axis.

```
rm(list = ls(all = TRUE))

if (!require("ggplot2")) install.packages("ggplot2")
if (!require("ggside")) install.packages("ggside")

# set theme

theme_set(
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_line(color = "black", size = 0.5, linetype = 1),
        plot.title = element_text(color = "black", size = 18,
                                  hjust = 0, vjust = 2),
        axis.title = element_text(color = "black", size = 16),
        axis.text = element_text(color = "black", size = 14),
        plot.tag = element_text(color = "black", size = 28),
        axis.ticks.length = unit(5, "pt"),
        plot.margin = margin(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, "cm"),
        panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", size = 1, linetype = 1, fill = NA),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(color = "black", size = 14),
        legend.text.align = 0.5,
        legend.background = element_rect(color = "transparent", fill = "white"),
        legend.key = element_rect(color = "transparent", fill = "white"),
        legend.margin = margin(5, 5, 5, 5, "pt")))

# contour

set.seed(230727)

z.1 <- runif(n = 100, min = -5, max = 20)
x.1 <- y.1 <- seq(1, length(z.1)/10, 1)
tmp <- expand.grid(x.1, y.1)
x.1 <- tmp[,1]
y.1 <- tmp[,2]

df.1 <- data.frame(x = x.1, y = y.1)
df.1$z <- z.1
df.1$level <- as.numeric(df.1$z)

# line plot

y.2 <- cbind(runif(n = length(z.1)/10, min = -5, max = 20),
             runif(n = length(z.1)/10, min = -5, max = 20))
x.2 <- seq(1, NROW(y.2), 1)

df.2 <- data.frame(x = x.2, y = y.2)

# plot data

ggplot(df.1, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_contour(aes(z = z, color = after_stat(level))) + 
  labs(x = expression(tilde(nu)[1] / cm^{-1}), y = expression(tilde(nu)[2] / cm^{-1}),
       tag = "A") +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),
                     position = "right") +
  theme(
    plot.tag.position = c(0.05, 0.95),
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.direction = "horizontal",
    legend.key.size = unit(0.5, "cm"),
    legend.key.width = unit(2,"cm"),
    aspect.ratio = 1) +
  ggside(x.pos = "top", y.pos = "left") +
  geom_xsideline(data = df.2, aes(x = x, y = y.1)) +
  geom_ysideline(data = df.2, aes(x = y.2, y = x), orientation = "y") +
  theme(ggside.panel.scale = 0.125,
        ggside.axis.text = element_blank(),
        ggside.axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

[image: plot 1 without expand scale]

The plot looks as expected.

When adding and expanded scale to the side plots using `scale_xsidey_continuous(expand = c(0.1, 0.1))` and `scale_ysidey_continuous(expand = c(0.1, 0.1))`, the distance between the left side plot and the main plot increases.

[image: plot 2 with expand scale]

When the side plot on the y-axis is on the right side, these commands don't affect the plot this way

[image: plot 3 with expand scale]

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Hello @Excelsior, would you mind opening an issue report [here](https://github.com/jtlandis/ggside/issues). Bugs like these may persist in the package until reported and ultimately sqashed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, while expanding the y scale for the x-side plot increases the spacing between the y side plot and the main plot this is IMHO an (unintended) side effect and most likely a bug.

This can be seen by checking out different values for the expansion, e.g. the default, your value of `.1` and a super large value of `10`:

- Adding some expansion on the side plot adds some spacing as a side effect. But the amount of spacing is independent from the amount of expansion.
- Expanding the scale does what it does: It expands the y scale of the (basis) side plot, i.e. using `expand=c(10, 0)` we get an almost flat line as a result.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggside)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- base +
  scale_y_continuous(
    expand = c(0, 0),
    position = "right"
  ) +
  ggside(x.pos = "top", y.pos = "left") +
  labs(
    title = "expand = default"
    )

p2 <- p1 + 
  scale_xsidey_continuous(expand = c(.1, 0)) +
  labs(title = "expand = .1")

p3 <- p1 + 
  scale_xsidey_continuous(expand = c(10, 0)) +
  labs(title = "expand = 10")
  

p1 + p2 + p3
```

[image]

I checked out the docs and the `ggside` source code but have not found any option to increase the spacing. One option to get more control would be to create your side plots as separate plots and glue them together using patchwork. As an example of this approach see e.g. my answers on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69507674/patchwork-doesnt-recognize-plots-with-ggmargnial-distribution-elements/69509320#69509320) or this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75250241/ggplotdata-df1-with-added-ggmarginal-data-df2/75250656#75250656).

If you want to stick with `ggside` I can only come up with a hacky workaround which uses a duplicated scale to add some spacing via the axis ticks. One drawback of this approach: It adds the spacing or margin on either side of the side plot (which makes me guess that this is the source of the aforementioned "bug" or side effect).

```
base +
  scale_y_continuous(
    expand = c(0, 0),
    position = "left",
    # Add a duplicated axis on the main plot
    sec.axis = dup_axis()
  ) +
  ggside(x.pos = "top", y.pos = "right") +
  # Remove the duplicated axis expect for the tick length to some spacing
  theme(
    axis.ticks.length.y.right = unit(20, "pt"),
    axis.ticks.y.right = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y.right = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y.right = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]

**Base plot**

```
base <- ggplot(df.1, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_contour(aes(z = z, color = after_stat(level))) +
  labs(
    x = expression(tilde(nu)[1] / cm^{
      -1
    }), y = expression(tilde(nu)[2] / cm^{
      -1
    })
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    expand = c(0, 0)
  ) +
  theme(
    plot.tag.position = c(0.05, 0.95),
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.direction = "horizontal",
    legend.key.size = unit(0.5, "cm"),
    legend.key.width = unit(2, "cm"),
    aspect.ratio = 1
  ) +
  geom_xsideline(
    data = df.2, aes(x = x, y = y.1)
  ) +
  geom_ysideline(
    data = df.2, aes(x = y.2, y = x), orientation = "y"
  ) +
  theme(
    ggside.panel.scale = 0.125,
    ggside.axis.text = element_blank(),
    ggside.axis.ticks = element_blank()
  ) +
  guides(color = "none")
```

Comment: thanks for your efforts and your answer. Since it could be a bug (and would maybe be fixed in the future) I will leaf ggside for now and try your approach using pathwork package